# Help with monotone convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Prove that if $E|X_1| < \infty$ and $X_n\uparrow X$ a.s. then either $EX_n\uparrow EX<\infty$ or else $EX_n\uparrow \infty$ and $E|X|=\infty.$

I just don't see how to use the fact that $E|X_1| < \infty$ before applying the monotone convergence theorem (I THINK that's the route to take).  I'm stuck honestly.

May someone give me some hints or even better a sketch of how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

The monotone convergence theorem seems to be the obvious way to go, but for
that you need a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative functions and it
is not given that $X_n >= 0$.

However, knowing that $X_1$ is integrable, and seeing that $X_1 + |X_1| >= 0$,
you can use the MCT on the sequence $\{ X_n + |X_1| \}$ to get the desired
result.